# Can you compute line segment that crosses a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a triangle with corner vertices `(x1, y1, z1)`, `(x2, y2, z2)`, `(x3, y3, z3)`. I also have a height `H` which is between `min(z1, z2, z3)` and `max(z1, z2, z3)` and I'm looking to find the coordinates of the line segment that crosses the triangle horizontally and has height `H`. Here's a little diagram:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3527zf1916yfss/Screenshot%202018-12-06%2015.41.09.png?dl=0

Context: I have mesh of triangles and am trying to draw the contour at a certain height `H`. I've found the triangles that the contour lines passes through, but not sure how to find the specific lines through each triangle.

Comment: Linear interpolation using the endpoints of the three sides will give you the endpoints of the segment.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\bbox{
\vec{v}_1 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix} \right ]
} \quad \text{and} \quad \bbox{
\vec{v}_2 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{matrix} \right ]
} , \quad \bbox{
z_1 \lt z \lt z_2 
}$$
then the contour at $z$ intersects the line segment between $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ at $\vec{p}$,
$$\bbox{
\vec{p} = \frac{z_2 - z}{z_2 - z_1}\vec{v}_1 + \frac{z - z_1}{z_2 - z_1}\vec{v}_2
}$$

In a triangle with vertices $\vec{v}_1$, $\vec{v}_2$, and $\vec{v}_3$, with $\min(z_1 , z_2 , z_3) \lt z \lt \max(z_1 , z_2 , z_3)$ there are exactly two such intersections; draw the line between those.

If we use $\vec{e}_{12}$ for the intersection point between vertices $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$, $\vec{e}_{13}$ for the intersection point between vertices $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_3$, and $\vec{e}_{23}$ for the intersection point between vertices $\vec{v}_2$ and $\vec{v}_2$, calculated using the above formula for $\vec{p}$ for each respective pair of vertices, the complete table of possible cases is
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z \text{ contour line or (point) } \\
\hline
z_1 \lt z & z_2 \lt z & z_3 \lt z & \text{None} \\
z_1 =   z & z_2 \lt z & z_3 \lt z & (\vec{v}_1) \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2 \lt z & z_3 \lt z & \vec{e}_{12} - \vec{e}_{13} \\
z_1 \lt z & z_2  =  z & z_3 \lt z & (\vec{v}_2) \\
z_1  =  z & z_2  =  z & z_3 \lt z & \vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_2 \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2  =  z & z_3 \lt z & \vec{v}_2 - \vec{e}_{13} \\
z_1 \lt z & z_2 \gt z & z_3 \lt z & \vec{e}_{12} - \vec{e}_{23} \\
z_1  =  z & z_2 \gt z & z_3 \lt z & \vec{v}_1 - \vec{e}_{23} \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2 \gt z & z_3 \lt z & \vec{e}_{13} - \vec{e}_{23} \\
z_1 \lt z & z_2 \lt z & z_3  =  z & (\vec{v}_3) \\
z_1  =  z & z_2 \lt z & z_3  =  z & \vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_3 \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2 \lt z & z_3  =  z & \vec{v}_3 - \vec{e}_{12} \\
z_1 \lt z & z_2  =  z & z_3  =  z & \vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_3 \\
z_1  =  z & z_2  =  z & z_3  =  z & \text{ Entire triangle } \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2  =  z & z_3  =  z & \vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_3 \\
z_1 \lt z & z_2 \gt z & z_3  =  z & \vec{v}_3 - \vec{e}_{12} \\
z_1  =  z & z_2 \gt z & z_3  =  z & \vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_3 \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2 \gt z & z_3  =  z & (\vec{v}_3) \\
z_1 \lt z & z_2 \lt z & z_3 \gt z & \vec{e}_{13} - \vec{e}_{23} \\
z_1  =  z & z_2 \lt z & z_3 \gt z & \vec{v}_1 - \vec{e}_{23} \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2 \lt z & z_3 \gt z & \vec{e}_{12} - \vec{e}_{23} \\
z_1 \lt z & z_2  =  z & z_3 \gt z & \vec{v}_2 - \vec{e}_{13} \\
z_1  =  z & z_2  =  z & z_3 \gt z & \vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_2 \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2  =  z & z_3 \gt z & (\vec{v}_2) \\
z_1 \lt z & z_2 \gt z & z_3 \gt z & \vec{e}_{12} - \vec{e}_{13} \\
z_1  =  z & z_2 \gt z & z_3 \gt z & (\vec{v}_1) \\
z_1 \gt z & z_2 \gt z & z_3 \gt z & \text{None} \\
\end{array}$$
There is absolutely nothing surprising in the table.

In practice, you can implement pseudocode similar to

```
Function z_contour(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, z)
    Let  x = [0, 0, 0]
    Let  y = [0, 0, 0]
    Let  n = 0

    If z1 == z:
        x[n] = x1
        y[n] = y1
        n = n + 1

    If z2 == z:
        x[n] = x2
        y[n] = y2
        n = n + 1

    If z3 == z:
        x[n] = x3
        y[n] = y3
        n = n + 1

    If (z1 < z and z2 > z) or (z1 > z and z2 < z):
        x[n] = ( (z2 - z)*x1 + (z - z1)*x2 ) / (z2 - z1)
        y[n] = ( (z2 - z)*y1 + (z - z1)*y2 ) / (z2 - z1)
        n = n + 1

    If (z1 < z and z3 > z) or (z1 > z and z3 < z):
        x[n] = ( (z3 - z)*x1 + (z - z1)*x3 ) / (z3 - z1)
        y[n] = ( (z3 - z)*y1 + (z - z1)*y3 ) / (z3 - z1)
        n = n + 1

    If (z2 < z and z3 > z) or (z2 > z and z3 < z):
        x[n] = ( (z3 - z)*x2 + (z - z2)*x3 ) / (z3 - z2)
        y[n] = ( (z3 - z)*y2 + (z - z2)*y3 ) / (z3 - z2)
        n = n + 1

    If n == 0:
        Return (None)
    Else
    If n == 1:
        Return Point(x[0], y[0], z)
    Else
    If n == 2:
        Return Line(x[0], y[0], z, x[1], y[1], z)
    Else:
        Return Triangle(x1, y1, z, x2, y2, z, x3, y3, z)

End Function
```

to compute the intersection of the contour $z$ and the triangle.